# Using array_multisort

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm using array_multisort at the beginning of a script after querying the database. Works fine. The arrays are sorted.

Later on in the same script, I use array_multisort again after another query to the database. The arrays are the same length for this second call but a different length than the arrays used initially.

I'm getting the "array_multisort array sizes are inconsistent" warning in my error_log. Are the arrays persisting from one call to the next and therefore, causing this error? If so, is there a way to clean up the function and remove the initial arrays used before the second call?

Here's a summarized view of the code with var_dump output included:

```
...1st query...

...1st array_multisort use based on the query...
array_multisort($shiftdate, $beg24, $uniquename, $subunit, $unit, $dept, $shiftdetail, $scheduledStaff);

...1st var_dump values based on array_multisort...
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["uniquename"]=>
    string(3) "Bob"
    ["shiftdate"]=>
    string(10) "2012-08-12"
    ["subunit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["unit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["dept"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["shiftdetail"]=>
    string(5) "7a-3p"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["beg24"]=>
    string(4) "7.00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(10) {
    ["uniquename"]=>
    string(4) "Cara"
    ["shiftdate"]=>
    string(10) "2012-08-12"
    ["subunit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["unit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["dept"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["shiftdetail"]=>
    string(5) "7a-3p"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["beg24"]=>
    string(4) "7.00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(10) {
    ["uniquename"]=>
    string(4) "Ryan"
    ["shiftdate"]=>
    string(10) "2012-08-12"
    ["subunit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["unit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["dept"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["shiftdetail"]=>
    string(5) "7a-3p"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["beg24"]=>
    string(4) "7.00"
  }
}


...2nd query...

...2nd array_multisort use based on the query...
array_multisort($shiftdate, $beg24, $uniquename, $subunit, $unit, $dept, $shiftdetail, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $scheduledStaffAndThoseWithDetail);

...NOTE: error_log warning occurs at this second array_multisort use...PHP Warning:  array_multisort() [<a href='function.array-multisort'>function.array-multisort</a>]: Array sizes are inconsistent...

...2nd var_dump values based on array_multisort...
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["uniquename"]=>
    string(4) "Ryan"
    ["shiftdate"]=>
    string(10) "2012-08-12"
    ["subunit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["unit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["dept"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["shiftdetail"]=>
    string(5) "7a-3p"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(4) "Ryan"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(5) "Dobbs"
    ["email"]=>
    string(17) "dobbsr@gmail.com"
    ["beg24"]=>
    string(4) "7.00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(10) {
    ["uniquename"]=>
    string(4) "Cara"
    ["shiftdate"]=>
    string(10) "2012-08-12"
    ["subunit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["unit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["dept"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["shiftdetail"]=>
    string(5) "7a-3p"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(4) "Cara"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(6) "Smith"
    ["email"]=>
    string(14) "cara@gmail.com"
    ["beg24"]=>
    string(4) "7.00"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Edited the question by adding a summary of the code.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the multisort entirely with an `ORDER BY` clause on the query?